# Adding a column to a .csv in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a nxn .csv file in which I am finding the cumulative sum of one column. I need to append this column with a header cumsum to the end of the existing .csv file to make it nx(n+1). How could this be done? I am attaching a samaple:

```
    filename     A      B
     aa          23     34
     aa          56     98
     aa          8      90
     aa          7      89
```

I am finding the cumsum of column A

```
      23
      79
      87
      94
```

I need this column appended to the end of .csv as

```
    filename     A      B     cumsum
     aa          23     34       23
     aa          56     98       79
     aa          8      90       87
     aa          7      89       94
```

I have 2 problems here:
1. I am extracting the column A everytime to perform the cumsum operation. How do I find it directly from the table for a single column without extraction?

2. How do I create a new column at the end of the existing table to add the cumsum column with a header 'cumsum'?

Answer (score 0):

**For point 1:** You can use [`csvread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) to read a specific column directly from a .csv file without loading the whole thing. For your example, you would do this:

```
A = csvread('your_file.csv', 1, 1, [1 1 nan 1]);
```

The `nan` allows it to read all rows until the end (although I'm not sure this is documented anywhere).

The use of `csvread` is applicable to files containing *numeric* data, although it works fine for the above example even with character entries in the first row and first column of the .csv file. However, it appears to fail if the part of your file that you want to read is *followed* by columns containing character entries. A more general solution using [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) is as follows:

```
A = xlsread('your_file.csv', 'B:B');
```

---

**For point 2:** Built-in functions like [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) or [`dlmwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) don't appear able to append new *columns*, just new *rows*. You can however use [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html), even though it is a .csv file. Here's how it would work for your example:

```
xlswrite('your_file.csv', [{'cumsum'}; num2cell(cumsum(A))], 1, 'D1');
```

And here's what the contents of `your_file.csv` would look like:

```
filename,A,B,cumsum
aa,23,34,23
aa,56,98,79
aa,8,90,87
aa,7,89,94
```

Comment: As my .csv files are a mix of character and numeric values I get mismatch error in line 147  while using `A = csvread('your_file.csv', 1, 1, [1 1 nan 1]);`